Excel hyperlink formula autodropdown needed
I need a solution that will enable me to auto-update links in the dropdown. The link contains the address to the workbook, which number should correspond to the given number considered in the row. If column A shows 185 I would like to have this number auto-updated in the link.
I dragged and dropped the row down and only columns A and B have been updated, as they don't have the links

I dragged the row with the number 179. Columns A and B have been updated, as they don't have hyperlinks. Other columns still retain the original number 179, which should increase too and show 185 eventually.
I know the INDIRECT function doesn't work properly as the linked workbooks must be opened.
Is there any solution for enabling autoincrement numbers within hyperlinks?

Did you copy past the cells ?

No, only dragged them down

Try concatenating the path and file name components with the column A value and nesting inside HYPERLINK().

How to do that?
